# How can I format string using computed key-value mapping?

Tags: python

I need something like that: `'{abc} {def}'.format(lambda key: compute_value(key))`. It looks like I need to implement a custom mapping for that:

```py
class Vars(collections.abc.Mapping):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return 'abc'
    def __len__(self):
        pass
    def __iter__(self):
        pass
```

Now if I try `'{abc} {def}'.format(**Vars())` I get `TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'NoneType'` error. For some reason it tries to iterate through my mapping.

Is there a simple way to format string using computed key-value mapping?

Comment: You mean like `f'{compute_value("abc")}'` or any of the countless template languages for Python?

Comment: @MattClarke unfortunately I can't, the properties have to be computed in lazy fashion.

Comment: The `**` operator expects an iterable, it can't know what "keys" it should ask for from the class with `__getitem__` so it iterates over all of them items.

Comment: "Need" is a strong word. Why exactly do you *need* this? Why can't you compute the values simply *before* calling `format`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`str.format_map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map), this way each item is fetched as needed and not expanded to kwargs via `**`

```
'{abc} {def}'.format_map(Vars())
```

Results in:

```
'abc abc'
```

Note: Python 3.2+ only